# How to solve error "The attribute 'securityTrimmingEnables' is unexpected in the configuration of the 'XmlSiteMapProvider' provider"

Tags: c#, web-config, asp.net-4.0, web.sitemap

I am new in ASP.NET..I create menu in web.sitemap and I want to hide some menu based on user logon..But I got this error "The attribute 'securityTrimmingEnables' is unexpected in the configuration of the 'XmlSiteMapProvider' provider". I want to know how to solve it?

Comment: why you not google it?Check this http://forums.asp.net/t/1196694.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Replace with `securityTrimmingEnabled`, you have mismatch

Comment: I have already set the <location path>, <allow roles> and <deny user> in web config..and I have already set the role in web.sitemap..I want to ask why the menu that I have already set only for admin also display when normal user login?